# Match string not containg a certain phrase

Tags: regex, string-matching

I need to find all instances of the word "confidential" in a message except when it is used in the phrase "confidential and proprietary" in which case it is ok and I dont need to pick it up through regex.

Thanks all in advance!
-P

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using word boundaries `\b` is also an option here.

```
\bconfidential\b(?! and proprietary\b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookaround (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

This regex will match: `(confidential) (?!and proprietary)` if your engine support lookaround.

demo: http://regexr.com?36itq

Comment: Surely you mean `confidential(?! and proprietary)`, as we otherwise replace `confidential[SPACE]`?

Comment: That's why I use () to capture "confidential" (we can imagine something more elaborate with Uppercase etc.). But yes, it is an other solution.