# awk lines not match

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Using `AWK`, I need to avoid print lines with a specific word in a specific field... 
Before someone call it's a duplicate, I did search, and found this: [Match string not containg a certain phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145348/match-string-not-containg-a-certain-phrase), but I think it's other context, because here I need match in a specific column.

Given the data:

```
ABC      ABC
DEF      AAA
GHI      ABC
```

I want to filter to print full lines only with text not containing ABC in fist field(lines 2 and 3).

As a first try, I tried `(?!...)` and expected to work this way to return `DEF` and `GHI`:

```
echo -e "ABC\tABC\nDEF\tAAA\nGHI\tABC" | awk '$1 ~ /(?!ABC)/ {print}'
```

but return nothing.

Second try... using not before the expression `!/.../` :

```
~$ echo -e "ABC\tABC\nDEF\tAAA\nGHI\tABC" | awk '$1 ~ !/ABC/ {print}'
```

Return nothing too.

I don't understand why...

So another shot fails (as expected this time):

```
~$ echo -e "ABC\tABC\nDEF\tAAA\nGHI\tABC" | awk '!/ABC/ {print}'
DEF     AAA
```

As expected this time, the second field was filtered too. So, it seems it work only to `$0`.

Then I did my homework and got it working this way:

```
~$ echo -e "ABC\tABC\nDEF\tAAA\nGHI\tABC" | awk '{FL=$0;$0=$1}; !/ABC/ {print FL}; { $0=FL }'
DEF     AAA
GHI     ABC
```

Anyway, this looks a workaround for me, and I have a bad feeling that I'm not doing in the right way.

Someone know a better way, or at least explain why the first and second tries do not worked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following idiom:

```
awk '$1 !~ /ABC/' file
```

If the first field does not contain `ABC` the line gets printed. (The *matches not* operator is `!~`). Note that the command contains a condition only and no `print` action. This can work since the default action in `awk` is `print` and therefore does not need to get specified explicitly.

Comment: thanks, your answer give me another way to, for record: 
`echo -e "ABC\tABC\nDEF\tAAA\nGHI\tABC" | awk '!($1 ~ /ABC/) {print}'
DEF     AAA
GHI     ABC`

Comment: Like I said, you can omit the `{print}` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '!/^ABC/' file
DEF      AAA
GHI      ABC
```

It will print lines not (`!`) starting (`^`) with `ABC`

Comment: Ok, In the sample I used the first field, but the question is about any field.